# Foxpro: Is it possible to disable external entity resolution?

Tags: xml, visual-foxpro, foxpro, xxe

Based on the documentation found here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/we9s91f8(v=vs.71).aspx

It appears that Microsoft Visual FoxPro is capable of conducting DTD parsing from external sources.

> "When you import XML using XMLTOCURSOR( ), Visual FoxPro uses an
>   external or internal schema to determine the cursor or table
>   structure. When no schema is provided, Visual FoxPro uses a "best
>   guess" method to interpret XML data. This involves two passes through
>   the XML, one to determine data structure and one to perform the actual
>   conversion. Note that the XML, in addition to being well-formed, must
>   generally conform to a format that can be interpreted as a table.
>   Well-formed XML that is not easily deconstructed into a table format
>   will fail to import"

However no information is given for how one might disable the parsing of external document schemas to prevent XML external entity injections. Is it possible to disable the parsing of external schemas, or must a strategy outside the language itself be employed to prevent the vulnerability?

Comment: I would imagine all you can do is set the relevant flag of 8192 to make it ignore external schemas altogether.

Answer (score 1):

As Alan said, if you supply 8192 as a parameter, then it would append to existing cursor. If there is no existing cursor, then:
It wouldn't parse with external schema if one is not included within the XML itself. If there is a schema inline within the XML, then you could still simply remove it using string operations. i.e.:

```
lcXML = FileToStr('c:\myfolder\my.xml')
lcXML = Strtran(m.lcXML, ;
   StrExtract(m.lcXML,'<xsd:schema','</xsd:schema>',1,1+4), '')
```

Using the XmlAdapter class, you could load this XML using your own external schema.

Note: CursorToXML() and XMLToCursor() predates XMLAdapter class and have limited capabilities. For a much better experience and to work with complex valid XML use XMLAdapter class instead (I believe I have posted code on foxite about how to parse complex XML using XMLAdapter many years ago).

Note2: Although documentation says that it uses external or internal schema, I don't know a way to supply external schema (haven't tried if simply having an .xsd file with same name would do it, if it does, then you could simply delete it or read the xml and use the string in memory with XMLToCursor()).